# Changing url in iOS Safari to manipulate the "Home Screen" bookmark url

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari, data-uri

I am trying to add a bookmark icon to the iOS home screen. I know this needs user interaction through Safari to add it and if I want my app to generate the html used by safari it all needs to be encoded in a data uri.
The problem i'm having, is when I load a data uri into safari, any created bookmark (home screen icon) will bookmark the data uri, so I need to somehow change the url that is being bookmarked.
The actual bookmark will be part of my apps url scheme so it opens up a section of my app. If I add a html link of the url on a page, it can't be bookmarked as once clicked it opens my app.

I somehow need to change the url that is being bookmarked by safari.

I have discovered that there is a method called `window.history.replaceState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/another-new-url”);` however when testing on a button, this doesn't change anything at all.

I've tried this code to change the url:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My App</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
window.history.replaceState("object or string", "New Title", "myurlscheme://another-new-url");
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function back(){
   window.history.back();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function forward(){
     window.history.forward();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Change URL">
        <input type="button" onclick="back()" value="back">
        <input type="button" onclick="forward()" value="forward">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and converted it into a data uri which results in this:

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,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
```

Even when testing this url on my Mac's safari, clicking the test() button does nothing.

There are other apps that can generate home screen bookmarks by showing the user a safari page for them to 'add to home screen', so it must be possible.

I am also looking at a worst case scenario of using a page on my server that my app can open in safari, however when trying to use php's `header("Location: myurlscheme://");` it just does an immediate redirect and launches my app instead of letting the user bookmark it.

Comment: I know this is insanely old but did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Reading my question back now, it is totally confusing and I have no idea why I was trying to achieve.